# In Zend SubForm, how do I set Legend escape to false?

Tags: html, escaping, legend, zend-form-sub-form

I've got a subform, where I set a legend.

```
$dob = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$dob->addElement($birthdayMonth)
->addElement($birthdayDay)
->setLegend('when is your birthday?');
```

How do I set the Legend so it won't escape the text?

Usually I'd get the decorator, but this doesn't work:

```
$decorator = $dob->getDecorator('Legend');
$decorator->setOption('escape', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Fieldset decorator, it passes it to the Legend field.

```
$dob->getDecorator('Fieldset')
    ->setOption('escape', false);
```